# PHP curl post with php session (same domain)

Tags: php, session, curl, post, request

I need to do a POST request from a PHP page (page1.php) to another PHP page (page2.php) in the SAME domain/application.

'Page2.php' uses session_start() to get some user stored info. That page can't be modified as it is used also for JS ajax requests, etc.
Also, 'page1.php' has session_start() as it also needs some user data.

The problem I have is that, If I make a cURL POST request from page1.php, then page2.php doesn't recognize the session (however, it works from JS ajax requests).

After a few hours trying to make it work, I finally found a solution:

[page1.php]

```
session_start();

$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/';

session_write_close();

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.com/page2.php",
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $useragent,
    CURLOPT_COOKIE => $strCookie,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [my_fields_array]
]);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

echo "$output";

curl_close($ch);
```

[page2.php] (just a minified sample)

```
$session_start();

echo $_SESSION['some_var'];
```

I also tried with CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, etc. but didn't work for me (don't know why).

After some tries, I finally noticed that the REALLY NEEDED line is this:

**session_write_close();**

But If I call the curl twice, it only works one of them.

I mean: If after a successful result, I 'refresh' page1.php, then the curl does not send the session (or page2 doesn't get it).

If I execute (refresh) page1.php again, then it will work again successfully, but will not work in the next refresh.

Is it possible to avoid this? Is the *session_write_close()* actually needed? Do I have to call session_start() again AFTER closing the curl or something?

I also tried with another methods to post data from php, but it seems all of them have the same cookies/session problem.

Comment: I'm curious about why you "need" to send a curl request if the PHP file is in the same application?

Comment: 'page2.php' was made and is prepared for getting post parameters and do some heavy stuff. I could just do a 'include page2.php' or similar, but I think it is easier to just make a cURL post. If there is an alternative, I will try it!

Comment: CURLOPT_COOKIE => $strCookie, worked for me. The COOKIEFILE and COOKIEJAR options did not work. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using *file_get_contents* instead of cURL.

I also have to pass $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] in the post header, but for any reason, file_get_contents is working but curl didn't keep session alive.

This is what I do:

```
   session_write_close();
   $result = savethisdoc($myfields,'page2.php');
   session_start();
```

And this is the savethisdoc function

```
function savethisdoc($postfields,$url)
{
    $query = http_build_query($postfields);

    $opts = array('http' => array('header'=> 'Cookie: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']."\r\n",'method' => 'POST','content'=> $query));
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    return file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
}
```

I'm iterating an array of 'documents' I need to save, so I need to call savethisdoc() for EVERY document in the array.

With curl, even saving/closing the session, it didn't work (session was not being keeped at all). But with this I can call 'page2.php' as many times as needed with no problem at all.

There is no reason why it works with file_get_contents and not with curl, so it must be something wrong in the cookie/session curl params.